# What are the different ways of consuming A WEB SERVICE

Tags: java

Can you please explain what are the different ways of consuming aws?
eg:we can consume a web service through http query
also using API 's.
is there any other ways to consume a web service other than this?

Answer (score 1):

To consume a web service you need a protocol.
You can find most of them here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_protocols

Comment: Thank you for your speedy replay.Can you please provide some links or tutorials that will explain more about these concepts in deep.I am concentrating on SOAP.I know this is some kind of stupidity but iam new in web service.

Comment: I don't know/have used enough about SOAP to give you more help on this. For REST i can recommend RESTeasy for starting ( http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/docs.html )

Answer (score 0):

To consume any web service you need to write client code in your preferred language which makes http call. 
Java has libraries like HttpClient through which you can consume any web services like SOAP based, XML-RPC based or even REST based.